# SSL certificate Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, socket.io

I've created my own Livechat, it works fine but after i tried to add my SSL Certificate it doesn't work properly anymore.

I tried different codes.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require("express");

var options = { 
    key:  fs.readFileSync('ca.key'), 
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ca.crt')
}; 

var expres = express()
  , app = require('https').createServer(options, expres)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { });

app.listen(8080);
```

and

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require("express");

var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('ca.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('ca.csr'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('ca.crt'),
    requestCert:        true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var expres = express()
  , app = require('https').createServer(options, expres)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { });

 app.listen(8080);
```

The three files exists with the content. (ca.key, ca.csr and ca.crt)

Sometimes i get a 107 (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) or sometimes the server don't even start.

Thanks,

Comment: you have a typo in 'app = require('https').createServer(options, expres)' it should be express and not expres

Comment: I don't think thats the problem? Thanks anyways.

Comment: Are you trying to verify keys from connecting clients (which is what the second example would do) or are you trying to just host the app itself over SSL? The name of the files `ca.*` seems to suggest that you're doing the former...

Comment: I'm trying to setup a SSL connection with this "server", the client will connect to https://[url].

Comment: Just wondering - how is the client connecting?  do you have the {secure: true} option there?

Comment: Yes. `socket = io.connect('https://[url]:8080', {
            secure: true
        });`

Comment: Your first example works fine for me when I use valid PEM key and cert. Your second example is definitely wrong as you're using a CSR file, which you'd never do in a server. A CSR file is only used for generating a certificate. Check that your key and cert are valid - use @user568109's advice to create some test files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the https server API http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_server. You will find it is a subclass of tls.Server

```
Class: https.Server
This class is a subclass of tls.Server and emits events same as http.Server.
```

On checking tls.server API http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener you'll see what all is required for the tls or https server:

```
key: A string or Buffer containing the private key of the server in PEM format. (Required)
cert: A string or Buffer containing the certificate key of the server in PEM format. (Required)
```

Since you are only using above two for one example. You should verify/test it with the required PEM  format. You can create it using instructions given here http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_ssl

```
openssl genrsa -out ryans-key.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key ryans-key.pem -out ryans-csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -in ryans-csr.pem -signkey ryans-key.pem -out ryans-cert.pem
```

After this you can check if other options are culprits or not, remove it when testing with the above certs.

```
//requestCert:        true,  
//rejectUnauthorized: false
```

Comment: This instructions for generating the SSL certificate are using openssl. Will you recommend this approach for production? If not, then what kind of certificate should we buy from the big guys (go daddy, rapids, etc) ? From what I've seen, if you buy a SSL from a certification authority, the KEY won't be exported.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar This is for personal use only. You would want to look at TLS than SSL for production. See https://luxsci.com/blog/ssl-versus-tls-whats-the-difference.html for how they compare. You should really ask this question in http://serverfault.com/ as they can answer it better and tell what are the differences among them and which one is best for you.

Comment: So not using the universally supported SSL and going for tls which your link says its accepted by less than 1% of browsers worldwide, seems to be the wrong decision, considering that my website is public

Comment: @AdrianSalazar Where does it say that. Besides that the post was written in 2008. Now TLS is the successor to SSL. All major browsers support TLS.